# Unexpected token - while parsing json request

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I have two node servers and I am trying to send files between them using a rest api. However when I am sending the data I get a "Unexpected token -"on the receiving server. On the sender I get an [Error: write after end].

My router code:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');

var Router = express.Router;

const MODULES_PACKAGES_UPLOAD_DIR = path.resolve('/tmp');

module.exports = function() {

var router = new Router();

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, MODULES_PACKAGES_UPLOAD_DIR);
  }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

router.post('/fileUpload', upload.array(), function(req, res){

  debug('We have a a file');

  //Send the ok response
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
  res.end('\n');
}
```

The sending code:

```
var Util = require('util');
var http = require('request-promise');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var Post = require('http');
var FormData = require('form-data');

//Generate the form data
var formdata = modules.map(function(fileName){
  return fs.createReadStream('/opt/files/'+fileName);
});

var data = getData(); //Gets the body of the code as a promise

return Promise.all(data)
.then(function(dataResults){

  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://' + name +'/file',
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    timeout: 2000,
    body: {
      keys: keyResults,
      modules: modules,
    },
    formData: {   <====== If I remove this section everything works
      'module-package': formdata,
    },
    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON 
  };

  request.post(options, function(err, response){
    if( err){
      debug('Error: ',err);
    }
    else{
      debug('We posted');
    }
  });
```

The weird thing is that if I remove the formData section then everything works but when it is there I get an exception that says:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
    at parse (/home/.../projects/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
```

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong??

Comment: If JSON parser says the JSON string is not valid - it's likely to be true. Provide the exact JSON it fails on.

Comment: It doesn't say. It just says -. All I know is that when I remove the formData there is no parse issue.

Comment: It does say there is a syntax error during parsing. Just check the `body-parser/lib/types/json.js` library source. "All I know is that when I remove the formData there is no parse issue" --- good, so remove it and the problem is resolved.

Comment: That is the equivalent of saying if there is a bug in the code just dont use that code. Unfortunately the formData section is critical to the application.

Comment: Ok, if is is then critical help us helping you - check the JSON that is parsed.

Comment: In a json request the form data section is binary data. It is not json. If it was I would pass it in the body.

Comment: You can't have both formdata and JSON. Choose either one.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you! That was why it wasn't working. Is there a way that I can embed the Json as apart of the form?

Comment: @nbroeking: You should be able to `JSON.stringify` your data, and append it as a file or post data to `formdata` next to the other ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case anyone in the future comes with the same problem. As @Bergi mentioned. You cant have both json data and form data. You need to choose either one. The solution is to just pass the json data as apart of the form like.

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://' + name +'/file',
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    timeout: 2000,
    body: {

    },
    formData: { 
      'module-package': formdata,
       keys: keyResults,
       modules: modules,
    },
    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON 
};

request.post(options, function(err, response){
    if( err){
      debug('Error: ',err);
    }
    else{
      debug('We posted');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the header of the HTTP Request contained "Content-Type" as "application/json".

So here are the things to check:

1. Send only either form-data or json body. NOT BOTH.
2. Check for Headers if the "Content-Type" is mentioned. Remove that.